# How to use play's incrementalAssetsCompilation

Tags: playframework-2.0

Has anyone been able to speed up their development by using incremental asset compilation according to http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.3/Assets ?

I can't get it to work, if I add incrementalAssetsCompilation := true to my Build.scala file I get a compilation error

> Build.scala:16: not found: value incrementalAssetsCompilation
>   [error]         incrementalAssetsCompilation := true
>   [error]         ^
>   [error] one error found

My Build.scala looks like this,

> ```
> val main = PlayProject(appName, appVersion, appDependencies, mainLang = JAVA).settings(
>     // Add your own project settings here
>     incrementalAssetsCompilation := true
> )
> ```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the commit regarding this feature did not made it to the 2.0.3 version :-(

If you look at the master version of the [PlayKeys.scala file](https://github.com/playframework/Play20/blob/master/framework/src/sbt-plugin/src/main/scala/PlayKeys.scala), you'll find the `incrementalAssetsCompilation` key, but not in the [2.0.3 version](https://github.com/playframework/Play20/blob/2.0.3/framework/src/sbt-plugin/src/main/scala/PlayKeys.scala).

Comment: Well this would explain it, thanks. It doesn't make me that happy though ;-) Feels like Play's quality is slipping a bit, lots of errors  and missing stuff in the documentation, slow development environment compared to 1.x etc.

Comment: Do not hesitate to provide this feedback on the mailing list: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/play-framework